# The number in the join of conjugate class and centralizer

Tags: gr.group-theory

I want to know that whether follow equality holds:
     $  |N_G(C_G(a)):C_G(a)|=|a^G\cap C_G(a)|.$
It is easy to see that the left hand is no more than the right hand. I think this equality does not hold, but I can't find a counter example.

Comment: I think this question would be better phrased: "If $b$ is conjugate to  $a$ and in $C_G(a)$, then there exists $c\in N_G(C_G(a))$ such that $b=cac^{-1}$."

Comment: @Will Sawin, your statement is weaker than the question. because you gave a map from one set to another. However, the question is only asking the equal cardinality statement. 

Comment: Since the map is always an injection, equal cardinality is the same as surjectivity.

Comment: You might be interested in this thread - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96652/cosets-and-conjugacy-classes - where there are some questions concerning the quantity $|a^G\cap C_G(a)|$ .

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I am very interested in the problem discussed in this thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $G$ to be a symmetric group of degree at least 5, and $a$ a transposition.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I have considered this group, but only considered the elements of order 3 and 5, where the equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Write $C$ for $C_G(a)$ and $N$ for $N_G(C_G(a))$.
Although, as Jeremy has demonstrated, the equality 
$|N:C| = |a^G\cap C|$ does not hold in general, it seems to me that there is a chance of characterising when it is true.

Consider, for instance, the situation when $C$ is a **TI-subgroup**. That is to say, 
$|C\cap C^g|$ is equal to $\{1\}$ or $G$ for every $g\in G$. I think it's fairly clear that in this case one does indeed have
$$|N:C| = |a^G\cap C|.$$

It seems to me that  *something like* a converse might also be true. I don't have the wherewithal to work this through right now but I will try and return to it in due course...

**Edit:** As Mark has pointed out in comments below, the TI-condition is too strong if we want to characterise when
$$|N:C| = |a^G\cap C|.$$
The condition that we want is this:
$$x\in G\backslash N \Longrightarrow h^x \not\in H.$$
The contrapositive might be clearer:
$$h^x \in H \Longrightarrow x\in N.$$

Clearly the TI-condition implies this, but it also accounts for the example given by Mark... And it's quite easy to see that it precisely characterizes when $|N:C| = |a^G\cap C|.$

Comment: Hi Nick. Maybe there is some sort of converse, but it will definitely need some extra hypotheses. For example, take $G = S_6$ and let $a = (123456) \in S_6$. Then $C = \left< a \right>$ and $N$ is the dihedral group of order $12$, so $|N : C| = 2$ and $a^G \cap C = \lbrace a,a^{-1} \rbrace$. But $C$ is not a trivial intersection subgroup of $G$ because both $C^{(23)(56)} = \left< (132465) \right>$ and $C$ contain $(14)(25)(36)$.

Comment: I think that the hypotheses that  $C_G(a)=\langle a \rangle$   also implies that equality holds

Comment: Wei Zhou, you are right, and the condition in the edit above confirms this.

Comment: Nick, do you know any groups satisfying the equality for every $h \in G$, except Dedekind groups?

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems to me that $G=C_p\rtimes C_{p-1}$ would satisfy the equality for all $g\in G$. In fact Frobenius groups are probably a good source of examples in general - one would just need to be sure that elements in the kernel satisfy the equality. Taking the kernel to be abelian would be enough (as for $G=C_p\rtimes C_{p-1}$) but there may well be other examples...

Comment: Nick, you are right. The Frobenius groups with abelian Kernel satisfy the equality. So these groups seem more than I thought.